# Using Session to store authentication?

Tags: asp.net, forms-authentication

I'm having a lot of [problems with FormsAuthentication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2964342/problem-with-asp-net-authentication)  and as as potential work around I'm thinking about storing the `login` in the `Session`?

```
Login:
Session["Auth.ClientId"] = clientId;

IsAuthenticated:
Session["Auth.ClientId"] != null;

Logout;
Session["Auth.ClientId"] == null;
```

I'm not really using most of the bells and whistles of `FormsAuthentication` anyway. Is this a bad idea?

Comment: What are the problems you're having with forms authentication?

Answer (score 2):

I would not store any valuable information in the session.

For authentication I would use:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
{
    // Then u use 
    // this.User.Identity.Name as my membership_id so i could call this everywhere
}else
{
    //Redirect to Login
    //gettting my LoginPageAddress
    Response.Redirect(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["LoginPage"]);
}
```

Login is something like this:

```
FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(membership_ID, false)
```

Anyway hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

i don't think it's an bad idea, i've seen plenty of sites using session together with a db to store auth data, however there are other ways to get around not using the formsauthentication tables but still be able to use things like roles.

[How do I create a custom membership provider for ASP.NET MVC 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2771094/asp-net-mvc2-custom-membership/2925372)

has good examples of that.